# How to access phpinfo.php?

Tags: php, iis-6

I am trying to access

```
http://localhost/phpinfo.php
```

but I can't find a way to get there on the local machine I made the update on.

This is part of a FastCGI installation to Host PHP Applications on IIS 6.0.

I followed steps here: 'Test PHP CGI' in http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis-60

I copied phpinfo.php as indicated in the link above in the F:\Inetpub\wwwroot directory as indicated here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms474356(v=office.12).ASPX 
then tried to access

```
http://localhost/phpinfo.php
```

but I don't get anywhere (I get: 'The webpage cannot be found' error message).

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks,
Izumi.

Comment: have you restarted your web server? also check if your firewall is not blocking web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the .php extension in the IIS Web Sites Properties as indicated here http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis-60 under 'MANUALLY CONFIGURE THE FASTCGI EXTENSION TO WORK WITH PHP'

I am not sure why the script didn't do it for me. Maybe because I had two domain names on that server.

Thanks for your help!
Izumi.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get all the information by saving a file with the following:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

and simply view that page.

While you are testing, you can drop it anywhere you like, but obviously remove it from a production box as anyone will be able to see it.